# Trying to delete SharePoint folder using API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, delete, api

I'm following this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest to try and delete a folder in a SharePoint library. I'm writing a c# console app but it's built using helpers from here (as I'll be using it within Dynamics CRM in the future) https://develop1.net/public/post/2014/12/29/SharePoint-Integration-Reloaded-e28093-Part-3.

It seems straightforward but if I send a null content in the post I get a 411 error 'Length Required'

```
        string odataQuery = $"_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{folder}')";

        string digest = _spo.GetRequestDigest();
        Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/{1}", _spo.SiteUrl, odataQuery));

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "DELETE");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine( url);
            byte[] result = HttpHelper.SendODataJsonRequest(url, "POST",null, webRequest, _spo);
            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }


//Code from the develop1 blog
    public static byte[] SendODataJsonRequest(Uri uri, String method, byte[] requestContent, HttpWebRequest clientHandler, SpoAuthUtility authUtility, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        if (clientHandler.CookieContainer == null)
            clientHandler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        //trace("Get Cookie Container");
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = authUtility.GetCookieContainer(); // get the auth cookies from SPO after authenticating with Microsoft Online Services STS

        foreach (Cookie c in cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri))
        {
            clientHandler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, c); // apppend SPO auth cookies to the request
        }

        return SendHttpRequest(
            uri,
            method,
            requestContent,
            "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8", // the http content type for the JSON flavor of SP REST services 
            clientHandler,
            headers);
    }
   public static byte[] SendHttpRequest(Uri uri, String method, byte[] requestContent = null, string contentType = null, HttpWebRequest clientHandler = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = clientHandler == null ? (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) : clientHandler;

        byte[] responseStream;


        request.Method = method;
        request.Accept = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"; // This must be here as you will receive 403 otherwise
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // This is key, otherwise it will redirect to failed login SP page

        // append additional headers to the request
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                if (request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains(header.Key))
                {
                    request.Headers.Remove(header.Key);
                }

                request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                //if (tracer!= null)
                //tracer.Trace(header.Key.ToString() + ": " + header.Value.ToString());
            }
        }


        if (requestContent != null && (method == "POST" || method == "PUT" || method == "DELETE"))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
            {
                request.ContentType = contentType; // if the request has a body set the MIME type
                                                   // if (tracer != null)
                                                   //tracer.Trace("Content Type: " + contentType);
            }

            string cont = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(requestContent);

            request.ContentLength = requestContent.Length;

            using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                s.Write(requestContent, 0, requestContent.Length);
                s.Close();

            }
        }

        // Not using Using here as you may still like to access the reponse outside of this method
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        responseStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return responseStream;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some responses pointing to manually adding a content-length header of 0 for this webRequest.

Note that it's a 'restricted header' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239725/cannot-set-some-http-headers-when-using-system-net-webrequest

so the code is

```
webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
```